# React router with Typescript (function class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying out Typescript with react (never worked before). I Solved a problem but I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it.

So my route in react looks like this

`<Route exact path='/show/:id' component={ShowIssues} />`

And my component solved is looking like this

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface RouteInfo extends RouteProps {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

const ShowIssues = ({ match }: { match: RouteInfo }) => {
  const { params }: { params: { id: string } } = match;
  const { id }: { id: string } = params;

  return <div>time to show the issue {id}</div>;
};

export default ShowIssues;
```

Is correct solved in the props this match? Surprisingly I've not found almost anything regarding function components ( and hooks are coming, so I guess makes sense to raise this doubt).

My other doubt goes for `const { params }: { params: { id: string } } = match;` is there a way I can reuse the `RouteInfo` so I don't have to type it twice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const { params }: { params: { id: string } }` and `const { id }: { id: string }` types are redundant because they will be inferred if `match` was typed properly.

Route props are an object with specific type that has `match` property, `RouteComponentProps`. It accepts `match.params` type as generic parameter.

It should be:

```
interface RouteInfo extends RouteProps {
    id: string;
}

const ShowIssues = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<RouteInfo>) => {
  const { params } = match;
  const { id } = params;

  return <div>time to show the issue {id}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't seeing it properly to type it every time neither.

Comment: Just to double check and make sure all good: with RouteComponentProps is already pointing into `params`, so I just have to specify the `id: string` in my type? with the wrapper of `params` was failing and without it looks good

Comment: That's correct. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L71 on how it works. I updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: Aren't RouteProps properties for `<Route />`? Extending them seems redundant here and actually raised weird TS errors for me. This works well enough:
`interface RouteInfo { ... `.